# Animation for a canvas object

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, canvas

I'm trying to use an animation for a sudoku app. I want for everytime i insert a wrong number, that number would change color and it's scale.
My code is:

```html
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas ?: return


     
        drawBoard(canvas)
        drawNumberProblem(canvas)
       


    }
    private fun drawNumberProblem(canvas: Canvas){


        paint.color=darkcolor
        paint.textSize = cellSide*3/4
        SudokuGame.numbersproblem.forEach { e->
            canvas.drawText("${e.number}", originX + e.col * cellSide+cellSide/5, originX + (e.row+1) * cellSide-cellSide/10,  paint)
        }
    }
```

And i tried:

```html
private fun initAnimation() {
        var animation = RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 150f, 150f)
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART)
        animation.setDuration(7500L)
        animation.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        startAnimation(animation)
    }





    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        canvas ?: return
        if(animation==null)
          initAnimation()
  


       
        drawBoard(canvas)
        drawNumberProblem(canvas)
       


    }
    private fun drawNumberProblem(canvas: Canvas){


        paint.color=darkcolor
        paint.textSize = cellSide*3/4
        SudokuGame.numbersproblem.forEach { e->
            canvas.drawText("${e.number}", originX + e.col * cellSide+cellSide/5, originX + (e.row+1) * cellSide-cellSide/10,  paint)
        }
    }
```

The animation, the board and the numbers are all good. The animation is only an example, i tried to rotate it to see if it's working. But the only problem is that the animation is working for the whole board, i want to have animation only over numbers.
Is there any way to create a initAnimation with a parameter like initAnimation(drawNumberProblem())?
I am new to kotlin animation, so i don't really care about the best way to do it, i want to find a simple way to understand it.
Thanks

Comment: When you create a custom view, overriding `onDraw`, you're responsible for how that view displays itself on the canvas. So if some elements of that display are animated, it's up to you to draw the current state of that animation for each frame (and call `invalidate()` so you get to redraw it next frame). So you'd need to keep track of animation states for each cell, and work out how to interpret that state when drawing each one - doable, but a little complicated. An alternative would be using separate `View`s for each cell (maybe just `TextView`s) and then you can use individual view animation

Comment: I see. I think i understand what you are saying. But i am a little confused with how can i do that. Do i need to create a animation function with parameters for the position of cell, or do i need to create a function of that cell that can be animated?

Comment: I've posted an overview of the general thing

Answer (score 0):

If each cell is its own `View` (say a `TextView`) you can animate it the way you're trying to, and the animation framework will take care of the timing, the rotation and scaling, etc. Because each view is separate, they can all be animated independently, using Android's view animation libraries, and a lot of the work is taken care of for you - it's pretty easy to use!

If it's all one view, and you're drawing a bunch of elements which can all be animated, you have to keep track of those elements, any animations that should be happening to each one, and how each animation's state affects the element when it comes time to draw it. Instead of each view having its own state and being drawn separately, you have to draw *the whole thing* at once, because it's a single view. So you need to keep track of those individual element states yourself, so you can refer to them when drawing the current overall state.

So for example, say you've got an animation where an element needs to scale to 2x the size and then back to normal, and it runs for 1 second total (1000ms). When you come to draw that element, you need to know how far along that animation you are at that moment, so you can scale it appropriately, and draw it at the correct size.

---

There are lots of ways to do this, probably some smarter ones, but this is the most basic hands-on example I think. I'm not testing this, but hopefully it gives you the idea:

```
// for brevity, so we can just say "now" instead of writing out the whole function call
val now: Long get() = System.currentTimeMillis()

// store a start time for each grid cell (or null if there's no anim running)
val animStartTimes = Array(CELL_COUNT)<Long?>

val animLength = 1000 // millis

// Basic function to start an animation - you could adapt this to prevent restarts
// while an anim is already running, etc
fun startAnim(cellIndex: Int) {
    animStartTimes[cellIndex] = now
    // tell the view it needs to redraw (since we're animating something now)
    invalidate()
}

// Get the current progress of an animation in a cell, from 0% to 100% (0.0 to 1.0)
// I'm treating a finished item as "reset" to its original state
fun getAnimProgress(cellIndex: Int): Float {
    val start = animStartTimes[cellIndex]
    if (start == null) return 0f

    val progress = (now - start) / animLength
    if (progress > 1f) {
        // animation has ended (past 100% of its runtime) so let's clear it
        animStartTimes[cellIndex] = null
        return 0f // like I said, I'm treating finished animations as "reset" to 0%
    } else return progress
}

override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    // this flag can be set to true if we find an element that's still animating,
    // so we can decide whether to call invalidate() again (forcing a redraw next frame)
    var animating = false
    items.forEachIndexed { i, item ->
        val animProgress = getAnimProgress(i)
        if (animProgress > 0f) animating = true // set that flag
        // now you need to use that 0.0-1.0 value to calculate your animation state,
        // e.g. adjusting the text size by some factor - 0.0 should produce your "default" state
    }

    // finally, force a redraw next frame if necessary - only do this when your view
    // contents might need to change, otherwise you're wasting resources
    if (animating) invalidate()
}
```

I hope that makes sense - obviously I haven't shown how to actually draw the states of your animation, that depends on exactly what you're doing - but that's the basics of it. It's a lot more work than using view animation, but it's not too bad when you get the idea.

The drawing part is a little more complex, and you'll probably want to get familiar with manipulating the `Canvas` - e.g. to draw a rotated character, you turn *the canvas*, draw the character as normal, then *undo the canvas rotation* so it's the right way up again, and the character is tilted. I don't have time to look for any tutorials about it, but [this article](https://riggaroo.dev/android-canvas-drawing-useful-graphics-classes-operations/) covers the matrix operations that scale/rotate/etc the canvas

---

So yeah, it's a bit involved - and depending on what you want to do, a grid of `TextView`s might be a better shout

Comment: What are the "items"? The things i try to animate? In my example, there will be "TextView"?

Comment: @TheUltra0 whatever you're drawing - numbers, icons, whatever. There's no TextView here, this is a custom view drawing the entire thing to a canvas, like in the example you posted