# I am calling simple draw rectangle in like 30 views at a time and having slow performance when calling postInvalidate every 50 milis

Tags: android

I want to have smooth look of my progress so I like 50 ms as it looks good but after some time my app stats to freeze ui randomly for seconds. When I change to 100ms everything looks fine just is not as smooth to my eyes. Any way to get better performance or trick so it looks better ?

Drawing code is like this:

```
 init {
        backgroundEach(50) { view.postInvalidate() }
        register(view.eventOnDraw.listen(::onDraw))
    }

    private val paint by lazy {
        Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
            color = view.foregroundTint
            isAntiAlias = true
            strokeWidth = dpToPixelF(30)
        }
    }

    private fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val position: Float = player.asStarted()?.inLoopIndex
            ?.div(player.commands.size.toFloat()) ?: 0f
        if (position > 0)
            canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, width * position, height.toFloat(), paint)
    }
```

And backgroundEach uses `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with one worker and standard `scheduleAtFixedRate( { function() }, delay, period, MILLISECONDS`

Comment: Have you seen/gone through: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render What does [systrace](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/tracing) show?

Comment: @MorrisonChang can you be more specific as to what part from there could be applicable ? I don't see there anything interesting just common things I already know. Now I am trying some postInvalidateOnAnimation and calling postInvalidate from handler .. seems like handler makes a difference still i believe I am missing something that allows greater performance.

Comment: It isn't clear why you are drawing so many rectangles and calling postInvalidate at that frequency rather than as required as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72294580/295004). Also identify how you are testing (device/emulator/OS version).

Comment: @MorrisonChang I am drawing progress of playback of sequences and also VU meters of audio outputs. I will maybe be able to optimize it more anyway I have to have great performance for audio processing and other UI interaction , saving of resources and so on so anyway I need it to go fluid now as it is with some heavy user interaction as stress test, maybe will be able to turn off some drawing of sequences but not sure about that because I cannot afford any performance loss when starting of play, this is midi synth sequencer and also audio looper app.

Answer (score 0):

I did some improvements:

Increaser executor threads to 3:

```
val executor = ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3)
```

and now posting on `view.postInvalidateOnAnimation()`

I also removed antialiasing as I don't see difference and maybe it eats some performance. Will see later if I have to dig into this more.